# Is there a way to prevent my application from running on sandboxie?

Tags: c#, sandbox

Is it possible to prevent or detect that my application is running on a sandboxie and not let it start or something alike ?

I have made a really silly easy game and have found out that people are using it on sandboxie in order to hack on it.

It constantly monitors the running process and other things to prevent hacks and while running on sandboxie the hack prevention in place becomes pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a *favourite-search-engine-here* search for GetModuleHandle sandboxie

Comment: I was under the impression that having my application running inside sandboxie would not allow me to pick such thing.

Comment: Sandproxie will inject a couple of DLLs so your process can run, a specific one might be an indication that your process is sandboxed. Note that this method might not be 100% reliable, as this dll name could be changed. Unless this is causing you damage, let them hack your game if their skill is not sufficient and use your energy to focus on new games/features